# How to read string from file using Groovy in QuickBuild

Tags: groovy, scripting, build-process, quickbuild

I am new to QuickBuild.

I have a lot of different versions stored in text files.
 To start the build process, I need to retrieve the versions from the text files and pass them to a shell script.

My question is: **How do I read the contents of a file using the QuickBuild environment?**
I know that it supports Groovy, MVEL and OGNL languages but I'm not familiar with any of them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :)

```
${groovy: str = new java.io.File("[PATH_TO]/file.txt").text}
```

or

```
${groovy: str = new java.io.File("[PATH_TO]/file.txt").text
str.split("[\\r\\n]")[0] }
```

to read the first line only.

Thanks to me :)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly shorter version for reading only the first line (which doesn't make any assumption about the EOL character):

```
${groovy: str = new File("[PATH_TO]/file.txt").readLines()[0] }
```